Cant print username on react
Im developing Fullstack React Web App project. In a component (which includes many stuff) cant display the username properly. And when i do other functions are broken. What is the problem on my codes and how can i fix it ?
In planning to create a gang component with fully capable of; create gang, promote-demote user, disband, quit(for members), fire members. And it will display the members for whom a member of. Is user not in a gang, it will fetch the avaible gangs and user can request join.
Its using store and zustand. I was trying to work it out for days and AI involved but i cant solve the problem. The usernames on the Gangs page not shown neither roles(promote-demote stuff). Its bigger than project now. It was on file so i seperated but its still same. If required/wanted i can share my zustand/store too.
If any editor readings this for approval i kindly ask for optimization for this question. Im really cozy head right now. Would you please help me to improve my question and make it more clear ? Is it too complex or not enough sharing ? I dont think its backend related because i see the names before and backend is simple and on console.log i can print. But is it needed to share the backend code or too much ?
Main page -> Gangs.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import GangDetails from './GangDetails';
import AvailableGangs from './AvailableGangs';
import useGangsStore from '../store/gangsStore';
import { fetchUserId, fetchUserGang } from '../services/gangsService';

const Gangs = () => {
  const { userGang, setUserId, setUserGang, setGangs, setLoading, setMessage } = useGangsStore();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { userId } = await fetchUserId();
        setUserId(userId);

        const userGangData = await fetchUserGang(userId);
        if (userGangData && userGangData.id) {
          setUserGang(userGangData);
        } else if (userGangData && userGangData.gangs) {
          setGangs(userGangData.gangs);
          setUserGang(null);
        } else {
          setUserGang(null);
          setMessage('No gang or available gangs found.');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching user or gang data:', error);
        setMessage('Error fetching user information.');
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);  // Important to stop loading
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [setUserId, setUserGang, setGangs, setLoading, setMessage]);


  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Gangs</h2>
      {userGang ? <GangDetails /> : <AvailableGangs />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Gangs;

The components ->
GangDetails.js
// frontend/src/components/GangDetails.js
import React from 'react';
import useGangsStore from '../store/gangsStore';
import {
  promoteGangMember,
  degradeGangMember,
  fireGangMembers,
  disbandGang,
  quitGang,
} from '../services/gangsService';

const GangDetails = () => {
  const { userGang, userId, gangJoinRequests, setMessage } = useGangsStore();
  console.log('GangDetails userGang:', userGang?.members);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Your Gang</h3>
      <p>Gang Name: {userGang.name}</p>
      <p>Leader Username: {userGang.leader_name}</p>
      <p>Members Count: {userGang.members_count}</p>

      <div>
        <b>Members:</b>
        <div>
          {userGang.members && userGang.members.length > 0 ? (
            userGang.members.map((member, index) => (
              <div key={index} style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <span>{member.username || 'Unnamed Member'} ({member.role || 'No Role'})</span>
                {userGang.leader_id === userId && member.role !== 'leader' && (
                  <>
                    <button onClick={() => fireGangMembers(userGang.id, member.username)}>
                      Fire!
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => promoteGangMember(member.username)}>
                      Promote to Crew
                    </button>
                    <button onClick={() => degradeGangMember(member.username)}>
                      Degrade to Member
                    </button>
                  </>
                )}
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>No members found</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {userGang.leader_id !== userId && (
        <button onClick={quitGang}>Quit Gang</button>
      )}

      {userGang.leader_id === userId && (
        <>
          <p><u>Join Requests:</u></p>
          {gangJoinRequests.length > 0 ? (
            gangJoinRequests.map((username, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <span>{username}</span>
                <button>Accept</button>
                <button>Decline</button>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <p>No join requests</p>
          )}
          <button onClick={disbandGang}>Disband Gang</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GangDetails;

gangsStore.js
import { create } from 'zustand';

const useGangsStore = create((set) => ({
  gangs: [],
  userGang: null,
  gangName: '',
  message: '',
  userId: null,
  loading: true,
  gangJoinRequests: [],
  username: '',

  setGangs: (gangs) => set({ gangs }),
  setUserGang: (userGang) => set({ userGang }),
  setGangName: (gangName) => set({ gangName }),
  setMessage: (message) => set({ message }),
  setUserId: (userId) => set({ userId }),
  setLoading: (loading) => set({ loading }),
  setGangJoinRequests: (requests) => set({ gangJoinRequests: requests }),
  setUsername: (username) => set({ username }),
}));

export default useGangsStore;

I have AvaibleGangs.js as well but its not related to my problem.

Before versions of code while i was close to complete the all functions, i was able to get console.log like this

Hi, Sorry if have not understood the issue correctly. If the statement userGang.members.map does not produce any lines, it means the userGang.members is empty. In order to debug it further, the hook useGangsStore would need to be investigated. If this observation makes sense, please share the code for useGangsStore.

Well its printing the members of gang also i can confirm from database. And its printing but without roles and names.
Current output:
Unnamed Member (No Role)
Desired output:
SomeNickName : Role(Member/Crew/Prospect)

Thanks. It means, member is a valid object still it does not have the properties username and role, therefore it prints the respective hard coded texts. BTW, just to make it clear, please do a console log of the object userGang.members just after this statement : const { userGang, userId, gangJoinRequests, setMessage } = useGangsStore(); If you can see the properties are missing in the listing, we need to inspect the hook useGangsStore.

Well the codes are changed a lot. For example in the last code fetchData(); was missing. Therefore there was no console.log because there was no fetching. Plus i removed the loading. All broken i guess. Finally i managed to get on the track again. Its logging like this:
GangDetails userGang:
['8'] i
0: "8"
length: 1

8 is the user id and 1 is only 1 member on the gang. If i fix one function the other is broken. Also creating and such problematic. I am editing the codes for last changed.

Hi, The troubles are momentary. It is the way to be fluent coding. There is no way other than continually doing the same. However, learning is also to keep going in parallel. Doing without learning will not yield benefits. Learning comes through code reviews, and reading and referring to technical documents. All will take its own time. All the more, be patient.

BTW, username and role are undefined as per the screenshots posted. It seems something to look into the hook useGangsStore and its underlying API call.

Thanks. How can i fix that ? So even if i can change back all 3-5 files to back and get the  state of in the screenshot; there is a problem. Thats way i cant move anymore with searching and AI and asking here. I cant able solve where is the problem and what is the solution. What should i do ?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Gathering as object and implying backend to this, solved it
